# Primefaces charts crashing chrome when exporting as image

Tags: jsf, primefaces, charts, export, jqplot

We are trying to export charts generated by `primefaces(jqplot)` through `exportAsImage` function:

```
function exportChart() {

    try {
        imgPie = PF('graphicPie').exportAsImage(); // this is an instance of p:pieChart
        document.getElementById('frmReports:b64_gr0').value = imgPie.src;
    }catch(err){  
    }
    try {
        imgBar = PF('graphicBarEvent').exportAsImage(); // this is an instance of p:barChart, here is where the script crashes 
        document.getElementById('frmReports:b64_gr1').value = imgBar.src;
    }catch(err){
    }

 }
```

The first chart (`pieChart`) exports with no problem, but when the script tries to export the second chart (`barChart`), the web page freezes and `Chrome` shows  `"Aw, Snap!"` exception.

This only happens in `Chrome` and only with clients in a different domain (if we test this script in the same machine where the application server is running, the script works fine).

`barChart` component code:

```
<p:barChart id="graphicBarEvent" widgetVar="graphicBarEvent"
    showDatatip="false" value="#{reportsMB.barEventModel}"
    legendPosition="n" style="height:170px; width: 100%;"
    seriesColors="#{reportsMB.factBarChartSeriesColors}"
    legendCols="3" extender="bar_ext" >
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{reportsMB.itemSelectFactBars}" /> 
</p:barChart>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, apparently there is a bug in jqplot function that was causing infinite loop in Chrome.

i had to override this JS function: jqplotToImageCanvas specifically this inner method:

```
  function writeWrappedText (el, context, text, left, top, canvasWidth) {
             var lineheight = getLineheight(el);
             var tagwidth = $(el).innerWidth();
             var tagheight = $(el).innerHeight();
             var words = text.split(/\s+/);
             var wl = words.length;
             var w = '';
             var breaks = [];
             var temptop = top;
             var templeft = left;

             for (var i=0; i<wl; i++) {
                 w += words[i];
               if (context.measureText(w).width > tagwidth && w.length > words[i].length) {
                     breaks.push(i);
                     w = '';
                     i--;
                 }   
             }
             if (breaks.length === 0) {
                 // center text if necessary
                 if ($(el).css('textAlign') === 'center') {
                     templeft = left + (canvasWidth - context.measureText(w).width)/2  - transx;
                 }
                 context.fillText(text, templeft, top);
             }
             else {
                 w = words.slice(0, breaks[0]).join(' ');
                 // center text if necessary
                 if ($(el).css('textAlign') === 'center') {
                     templeft = left + (canvasWidth - context.measureText(w).width)/2  - transx;
                 }
                 context.fillText(w, templeft, temptop);
                 temptop += lineheight;
                 for (var i=1, l=breaks.length; i<l; i++) {
                     w = words.slice(breaks[i-1], breaks[i]).join(' ');
                     // center text if necessary
                     if ($(el).css('textAlign') === 'center') {
                         templeft = left + (canvasWidth - context.measureText(w).width)/2  - transx;
                     }
                     context.fillText(w, templeft, temptop);
                     temptop += lineheight;
                 }
                 w = words.slice(breaks[i-1], words.length).join(' ');
                 // center text if necessary
                 if ($(el).css('textAlign') === 'center') {
                     templeft = left + (canvasWidth - context.measureText(w).width)/2  - transx;
                 }
                 context.fillText(w, templeft, temptop);
             }

         }
```

In chrome when "words" is "0" this results in an infinite loop.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue... How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the attribute `setShowPointLabels(true)` on bean, try to remove it. This worked for me.

Thanks to fpoulet on this post:
https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=52739