# jqplotToImageCanvas not working in chrome version 47.0 and firefox 41.0.1

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, canvas, jqplot

I have multiple charts generated by PHPChart but when i use from print option to print the chart in pdf, and png in chrome it is not working for bar chart types but work for line chart, but if there is one bar chart it works, in Firefox it is not working for vertical bar chart but work for horizontal bar chart.
all type of charts are generated dynamically using database data there is no difference in case of html wrapper tags. 
when i click on export button browser hung up.

The javascript code:

```
function getImageData(obj, type, title)
{
    var str;

    imgtype = type;

    if (type == 'jpg-pdf')
    {
        imgtype = 'jpg';
        type = 'pdf';
    }
    var imgCanvas = $('#'+obj).jqplotToImageCanvas();

    if (imgCanvas) {
        str = imgCanvas.toDataURL("image/"+imgtype);
    }
    else {
        str = null;
    }

    $('#pngdata').val(str);
    $('#imgtype').val(type);
    $('#imgtitle').val(title);

    $('#imgform').submit();

}
```

and the jqplot function

```
 $.fn.jqplotToImageCanvas = function(options) {

    options = options || {};
    var x_offset = (options.x_offset == null) ? 0 : options.x_offset;
    var y_offset = (options.y_offset == null) ? 0 : options.y_offset;
    var backgroundColor = (options.backgroundColor == null) ? 'rgb(255,255,255)' : options.backgroundColor;

    if ($(this).width() == 0 || $(this).height() == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    // excanvas and hence IE < 9 do not support toDataURL and cannot export images.
    if ($.jqplot.use_excanvas) {
        return null;
    }

    var newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var h = $(this).outerHeight(true);
    var w = $(this).outerWidth(true);
    var offs = $(this).offset();
    var plotleft = offs.left;
    var plottop = offs.top;
    var transx = 0, transy = 0;

    // have to check if any elements are hanging outside of plot area before rendering,
    // since changing width of canvas will erase canvas.

    var clses = ['jqplot-table-legend', 'jqplot-xaxis-tick', 'jqplot-x2axis-tick', 'jqplot-yaxis-tick', 'jqplot-y2axis-tick', 'jqplot-y3axis-tick',
        'jqplot-y4axis-tick', 'jqplot-y5axis-tick', 'jqplot-y6axis-tick', 'jqplot-y7axis-tick', 'jqplot-y8axis-tick', 'jqplot-y9axis-tick',
        'jqplot-xaxis-label', 'jqplot-x2axis-label', 'jqplot-yaxis-label', 'jqplot-y2axis-label', 'jqplot-y3axis-label', 'jqplot-y4axis-label',
        'jqplot-y5axis-label', 'jqplot-y6axis-label', 'jqplot-y7axis-label', 'jqplot-y8axis-label', 'jqplot-y9axis-label' ];

    var temptop, templeft, tempbottom, tempright;

    for (var i = 0, j = clses.length; i < j; i++) {
        $(this).find('.'+clses[i]).each(function() {
            temptop = $(this).offset().top - plottop;
            templeft = $(this).offset().left - plotleft;
            tempright = templeft + $(this).outerWidth(true) + transx;
            tempbottom = temptop + $(this).outerHeight(true) + transy;
            if (templeft < -transx) {
                w = w - transx - templeft;
                transx = -templeft;
            }
            if (temptop < -transy) {
                h = h - transy - temptop;
                transy = - temptop;
            }
            if (tempright > w) {
                w = tempright;
            }
            if (tempbottom > h) {
                h =  tempbottom;
            }
        });
    }

    newCanvas.width = w + Number(x_offset);
    newCanvas.height = h + Number(y_offset);

    var newContext = newCanvas.getContext("2d");

    newContext.save();
    newContext.fillStyle = backgroundColor;
    newContext.fillRect(0,0, newCanvas.width, newCanvas.height);
    newContext.restore();

    newContext.translate(transx, transy);
    newContext.textAlign = 'left';
    newContext.textBaseline = 'top';

    function getLineheight(el) {
        var lineheight = parseInt($(el).css('line-height'), 10);

        if (isNaN(lineheight)) {
            lineheight = parseInt($(el).css('font-size'), 10) * 1.2;
        }
        return lineheight;
    }

    function writeWrappedText (el, context, text, left, top, canvasWidth) {
        var lineheight = getLineheight(el);
        var tagwidth = $(el).innerWidth();
        var tagheight = $(el).innerHeight();
        var words = text.split(/\s+/);
        var wl = words.length;
        var w = '';
        var breaks = [];
        var temptop = top;
        var templeft = left;

        for (var i=0; i<wl; i++) {
            w += words[i];
            if (context.measureText(w).width > tagwidth && w.length > words[i].length) {
                breaks.push(i);
                w = '';
                i--;
            }
        }
        if (breaks.length === 0) {
            // center text if necessary
            if ($(el).css('textAlign') === 'center') {
                templeft = left + (canvasWidth - context.measureText(w).width)/2  - transx;
            }
            context.fillText(text, templeft, top);
        }
        else {
            w = words.slice(0, breaks[0]).join(' ');
            // center text if necessary
            if ($(el).css('textAlign') === 'center') {
                templeft = left + (canvasWidth - context.measureText(w).width)/2  - transx;
            }
            context.fillText(w, templeft, temptop);
            temptop += lineheight;
            for (var i=1, l=breaks.length; i<l; i++) {
                w = words.slice(breaks[i-1], breaks[i]).join(' ');
                // center text if necessary
                if ($(el).css('textAlign') === 'center') {
                    templeft = left + (canvasWidth - context.measureText(w).width)/2  - transx;
                }
                context.fillText(w, templeft, temptop);
                temptop += lineheight;
            }
            w = words.slice(breaks[i-1], words.length).join(' ');
            // center text if necessary
            if ($(el).css('textAlign') === 'center') {
                templeft = left + (canvasWidth - context.measureText(w).width)/2  - transx;
            }
            context.fillText(w, templeft, temptop);
        }

    }

    function _jqpToImage(el, x_offset, y_offset) {
        var tagname = el.tagName.toLowerCase();
        var p = $(el).position();
        var css = window.getComputedStyle ?  window.getComputedStyle(el, "") : el.currentStyle; // for IE < 9
        var left = x_offset + p.left + parseInt(css.marginLeft, 10) + parseInt(css.borderLeftWidth, 10) + parseInt(css.paddingLeft, 10);
        var top = y_offset + p.top + parseInt(css.marginTop, 10) + parseInt(css.borderTopWidth, 10)+ parseInt(css.paddingTop, 10);
        var w = newCanvas.width;
        // var left = x_offset + p.left + $(el).css('marginLeft') + $(el).css('borderLeftWidth') 

        // somehow in here, for divs within divs, the width of the inner div should be used instead of the canvas.

        if ((tagname == 'div' || tagname == 'span') && !$(el).hasClass('jqplot-highlighter-tooltip')) {
            $(el).children().each(function() {
                _jqpToImage(this, left, top);
            });
            var text = $(el).jqplotChildText();

            if (text) {
                newContext.font = $(el).jqplotGetComputedFontStyle();
                newContext.fillStyle = $(el).css('color');

                writeWrappedText(el, newContext, text, left, top, w);
            }
        }

        // handle the standard table legend

        else if (tagname === 'table' && $(el).hasClass('jqplot-table-legend')) {
            newContext.strokeStyle = $(el).css('border-top-color');
            newContext.fillStyle = $(el).css('background-color');
            newContext.fillRect(left, top, $(el).innerWidth(), $(el).innerHeight());
            if (parseInt($(el).css('border-top-width'), 10) > 0) {
                newContext.strokeRect(left, top, $(el).innerWidth(), $(el).innerHeight());
            }

            // find all the swatches
            $(el).find('div.jqplot-table-legend-swatch-outline').each(function() {
                // get the first div and stroke it
                var elem = $(this);
                newContext.strokeStyle = elem.css('border-top-color');
                var l = left + elem.position().left;
                var t = top + elem.position().top;
                newContext.strokeRect(l, t, elem.innerWidth(), elem.innerHeight());

                // now fill the swatch

                l += parseInt(elem.css('padding-left'), 10);
                t += parseInt(elem.css('padding-top'), 10);
                var h = elem.innerHeight() - 2 * parseInt(elem.css('padding-top'), 10);
                var w = elem.innerWidth() - 2 * parseInt(elem.css('padding-left'), 10);

                var swatch = elem.children('div.jqplot-table-legend-swatch');
                newContext.fillStyle = swatch.css('background-color');
                newContext.fillRect(l, t, w, h);
            });

            // now add text

            $(el).find('td.jqplot-table-legend-label').each(function(){
                var elem = $(this);
                var l = left + elem.position().left;
                var t = top + elem.position().top + parseInt(elem.css('padding-top'), 10);
                newContext.font = elem.jqplotGetComputedFontStyle();
                newContext.fillStyle = elem.css('color');
                writeWrappedText(elem, newContext, elem.text(), l, t, w);
            });

            var elem = null;
        }

        else if (tagname == 'canvas') {
            newContext.drawImage(el, left, top);
        }
    }
    $(this).children().each(function() {
        _jqpToImage(this, x_offset, y_offset);
    });
    return newCanvas;
};
```

kindly help me.[image]

Comment: Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27408970